# How to create hyperlink in PDF using jsPDF js library?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

JavaScript:

```
    function demoJsPdf() {
        var doc = new jsPDF("landscape", "mm", "a4");

        doc.setFontSize(22);
        doc.text(20, 20, 'This is a exmaple of jsPDF');

        doc.setFontSize(16);
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This example is created by dsharma4u29.');
        doc.fromHTML('<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>', 20, 60, {'width': 10, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers});

        var iframe = document.getElementById('output');
        iframe.style.width = '100%';
        iframe.style.height = '400px';
        iframe.src = doc.output('datauristring');
    }

    var specialElementHandlers = function() {
        return;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <div>
        <a href="javascript:demoJsPdf()" class="button">Run Code 2</a>
    <iframe id="output"></iframe>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Now the text "Run Code 2" must be shown as hyper link but it is just being displayed as simple text, not a hyper link. How can I achieve it as a hyper link on the PDF?

Comment: Hyperlinks aren't supported yet, there is someone who implemented it but didn't yet release it to the public, feel free hurry him: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/170#issuecomment-46093835 :-)

Answer (score 15):

jsPDF has two tools for adding hyperlinks, `.link()` and `.textWithLink()`, which have been available since Nov. 2014. They're not well documented, but you can find some info on how to use them [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/170#issuecomment-293975156).

```
// Create text 'Hello World!' with a link
doc.textWithLink('Hello World!', 25, 25, {url: 'https://www.example.com/'});

// Create a rectangle and place a link box on top of it.
doc.rect(25, 50, 25, 25, 'FD');
doc.link(25, 50, 25, 25, {url: 'https://www.example.com/'});
```

You can also use my library [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf), which renders any HTML into PDF and automatically adds hyperlinks for all `<a>` anchor tags.

Comment: Is there a way to make those links open in a new tab?

Answer (score 5):

With the current version everything links automatically as long as you have the whole URL written out

Example:`doc.text(20, 30, 'http://www.google.com');`

Will automatically link to Google.

It's a hack, but if you need it on a button or image or something, the easiest answer is just to hide the text URL in the same spot on the top layer. Watch hiding it on top of actual text, though- it tends to jumble together and you end up with a URL that is a combination of the two.

Comment: Though it doesn't give one the same flexibility of a hyperlink, this is good to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.textWithLink()`](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-annotations.html#~textWithLink) to mimic standard HTML hyperlinks.

```
doc.textWithLink('Vist StackOverflow here', posX, posY, {url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pilotkid/cojy1rv6/18) with an example.

---

Also as [@Erin Kerrigan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5063255/erin-kerrigan) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126907/2073738) if you just specify a link as a regular text object it will automatically become a link

```
doc.text(20, 30, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```